# How can I know if its same user but different IP.

Tags: .net, ip

We get lot of fake users on our website.

We block them from IP addresses or email addresses but found that they come back again from different ip's 
How we can know if its same user whom we blocked ?  (please note we need to block them before they login  ) 
our website is in .net

Comment: Is there a registration process too? Is it open to anyone?

Answer (score 0):

Attempt to create a cookie on the client via `Set-Cookie` header, that will signify a GUID for example, and store these in a temporary table. So, if those users don't use priovate browsing, their cookie will be accessible, and thus if you'd find a GUID cookie in your blocked list, this client was once blocked by IP/email, thus the same. But most likely you will be unable to do this, either by the fact that they need to connect to your site after being banned to get that cookie, or by them using private browsing which clears cookies.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer, you can't.  Every identifying feature of a connection can be changed if you want to bad enough.  The only real solution is to limit the damage that can be done without an approved account.